# Data error when inflating the zlib stream object

Tags: pdf, zlib, inflate

I am trying to inflate an object stream in a pdf. While inflating one of the object stream which is compressed with flate decode I am getting data error.

**Object stream**
1339 0 obj^M<</First 7/Length 36/Filter/FlateDecode/N 1/Type/ObjStm>>stream^M

^ZÖ¬Áã9^<87>^GÎ<89><93>^WÊ<8d>ð<93>yM<96>t0Ò=$Ô<·×^L<84>°¯$<8b>^M
endstream

**Encryption object **
1698 0 obj^M<</Length 128/Filter/Standard/O(¡"ÎÙ¢¬<9d><9c>­"\r^S^LÀõeâJý;Î{dTÔÜ<9d>~´>^Tº)/P -1324/R 3/U(É^[®ú^F^C /¬®=ÌæZv5');\r\n             view( a)/V 2>>^Mendobj

**After decrypting I got this data**
{0x68, 0x16, 0x48, 0x59, 0x11, 0xef, 0x34, 0xe9, 0xd0, 0x79, 0xf6, 0xcb, 0x73, 0xf6, 0x8a, 0x50, 0xed, 0xdc, 0x34, 0xe9, 0x60, 0xb1, 0xbf, 0x3, 0xf5, 0x92, 0x5, 0x67, 0x60, 0xd9, 0x84, 0x34, 0x44, 0xad, 0xa9, 0x5c}
Now I have to uncompress this data.

I am getting data error after calling inflate(&zstrm, Z_FINISH);
I am stuck here. Can anyone please help me to understand this error.

Ans :

Here the input I was supplying to zlib was not a valid inflate data. When the input stream was encrypted the first character was new line character. I was skipping that newline character. That was the error.

Comment: A zlib/deflate stream can't start with 0x6816, the compression info is out of range and the check bits don't match (read [RFC 1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt) for more details). Are you sure you've decrypted correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion@ephemient.    In RFC 1950 
            bits 0 to 3  CM     Compression method
            bits 4 to 7  CINFO  Compression info         This bit representation is from left to right or right to left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a zlib stream, nor is it even raw deflate data.